# Determine whether a set of Java files can be made executable, or is just a library

Tags: java

How can I tell whether a bunch of Java files can be made executable, or is just a library, and can't be made executable?

From http://www.bugaco.com/bioinf/clusterer/ , by clicking on "Download sources", I downloaded a zip file containing a bunch of files, most of which were .java files. The folders were `com`, `conf`, and `META-INF`.

I can't tell whether, once the files are compiled, there's supposed to be an executable that I can run, or whether it's just a library, and I would have to write the main application myself (which I can't do, because although I program in Ruby, I don't currently program in Java).

I tried reading the manual, but this is the entirety of the documentation with regards to running it as an application. (I also suspect that the person writing the documentation isn't a fluent speaker of English)

> **Run as an Application**
>
> Running Clusterer as application is only recommended if you are planning to extend the application. To run
>   clusterer as an application, please download source code from the
>   Clusterer homepage by clicking on “Download sources” link, and extract
>   source code. Please use Java Development Kit (JDK) 1.4 on newer to
>   re-compile and execute source.

How can I determine if the files I've downloaded are capable of being compiled and being made an executable program that I can run, or if it's just a library?

(I've asked this in Super User, rather than Stack Overflow, because I'm just trying to use a program, if it is a program, and not writing a program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the given link, it is a Java applet application. you can run this in the following ways.

1.You can run as a applet in the browser itself.

2.You can run using java web start by downloading .jnlp file (use javaws.exe to run in windows)

3.If you want to run this as a standalone java application, you have to download the source code and compile it using jdk. (this you can do in case you want to modify something in the application. apart from the current functionalities.)

Comment: How were you able to determine that `3.` is possible?

Comment: it is obvious that if you are provided with the source code you can modify(enhance) the source code according to you needs and re-deploy it as an executables. In above case some java files are compiled and deployed as java applets. and they are mentioning that you can recompile them to enhance the functionality of the application.